Finding position of zero nibble in 64 bits
I am given a 64bit number, made up of 16 nibbles (chunks of 4 bits). I know that there is a single nibble within them that is zero (0b0000) and I need to find it's index (0-15).
My constraints are that I cannot use iteration, loops or branching (if/else).
I can only use bit manipulation, but I do have access to builtin functions such as __builtin_ctzll or __builtin_ffsll (I am using GCC).
I don't have very good grasp on bit manipulation, so so far I've only tried the following:
x |= x >> 1;
x |= x >> 2;

This seems to give some sort of idea for where the target nibble is but I can't really find the next step and it has plenty of cases where it doesn't work as intended...
I've also looked at an extremely similar question: Fast lookup of a null nibble in a 64 bit unsigned
The answer provided suggests that the following function should work:
int zero_nibble_position (uint64_t a)
{
    const uint64_t nibble_lsb = 0x1111111111111111ULL;
    const uint64_t nibble_msb = 0x8888888888888888ULL; 
    uint64_t t = (a - nibble_lsb) & (~a & nibble_msb);
    return __builtin_clzll(t)/4;
}

For some inputs it does work, but sometimes not.
For example, 0b0001000000111010010101100111001010010001010011001101111011111011 (1169342103320059643) should return 1, but instead returns 0.
In general, as soon as the 0b0000 nibble is after a 0b0001 it gets the index wrong

A property of Alan Mycroft's null-byte detection algorithm (adapted for nibbles here) is that this trick reliably detects the lowest (least-significant) zero, but the bits of the result to the left (more-significant bits) of that zero do not reliably indicate zeroes or non-zeroes.
When you use a bit scan that counts from the least significant bit up, as the linked answer does, then that doesn't matter: either there is no zero (and so no troublesome bits), or there is a zero and a bit scan from the least significant bit up will ignore the unreliable part of the result.
Using a scan from the most significant bit down, such as __builtin_clzll, is affected by the unreliable part of the result. So these things cannot be combined.

If you can use the index of the least-significant zero nibble (you should be able to do this, since you indicated that only one nibble will be zero), you can keep using the variant of Mycroft's zero detection technique, but combine it with __builtin_ctzll (in C23 you may be able to use stdc_trailing_zeros from stdbit.h as a portable option).

If you need the index of the most-significant zero nibble, you need a different zero-nibble-detection without that property that the more-significant bits above a zero are unreliable. You weren't far off from constructing one. For example:
x |= x >> 1;
x |= x >> 2;
// the least significant bit of every nibble indicates
// whether the corresponding nibble was non-zero
// keep only that bit, but inverted
x = ~x & 0x1111111111111111ULL;




Curious, why the unneeded LL in 0x1111111111111111ULL?

Thank you very much, it works perfectly and is simple enough to be understood!
As for why the LL, that is because ULL stands for unsigned long long which corresponds to the uint64_t type that I am working with
